# How to resolve Connection error in couchdb android?

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

Getting below error while connecting CouchDB server using Replicator

```
Status{activityLevel=CONNECTING,
       progress=Progress{completed=0, total=0},
       error=CouchbaseLiteException{CouchbaseLite,11001,'WebSocket connection closed by peer'}}

Status{activityLevel=STOPPED,
       progress=Progress{completed=0, total=0},
       error=CouchbaseLiteException{CouchbaseLite,11001,'WebSocket connection closed by peer'}}
```

Below is my code;

```
  Replicator replicator = null;

    try {
        CouchbaseLite.init(context);
        Database.setLogLevel(LogDomain.ALL, LogLevel.ERROR);
        DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration = new DatabaseConfiguration();
        Database database = new Database("company-3", databaseConfiguration);

        URLEndpoint target = new URLEndpoint(new URI("ws://*****/company-3/"));

        ReplicatorConfiguration config = new ReplicatorConfiguration(database, target);
        config.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator("username", "password"));

        replicator = new Replicator(config);
        replicator.start();


    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Dependancy:

```
 implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.7.0'
```

Comment: Couchbase Lite 2.x is not compatible with CouchDB

Comment: Couchbase Lite uses Sync Gateway and Couchbase Server. Please post the log of your sync gateway

Comment: I already posted logs in yellow background @deniswsrosa

Comment: Then which version is compatible with CouchDB @JuanjoRodriguez?

Comment: Are you using CouchDB or Couchbase in the server? If Couchdb, Couchbase Lite 1.x is compatible with CouchDB's replication protocol. You can also try with other Android clients like Cloudant Sync.

Comment: I am using couchdb. Is this version depend upon sync gateway version or not? @JuanjoRodriguez