# How to connect Couchbase with couchbase lite version 2.7?

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase, couchbase-lite

Code

```
Replicator replicator = null;

try {
    CouchbaseLite.init(context);
    Database.setLogLevel(LogDomain.ALL, LogLevel.ERROR);
    DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration = new DatabaseConfiguration();
    Database database = new Database("company-3", databaseConfiguration);

    URLEndpoint target = new URLEndpoint(new URI("ws://*****:5984/company-3/"));

    ReplicatorConfiguration config = new ReplicatorConfiguration(database, target);
    config.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator("username", "password"));

    replicator = new Replicator(config);
    replicator.start();


} catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Getting below error while connecting the CouchDB server using Replicator to android client

```
ReplicatorChange{replicator=Replicator{@84dac64,<*>,Database{@58eedf6, name='company-3'},URLEndpoint{url=ws:/ /*****:5984/company-3/}], status=Status{activityLevel=CONNECTING, progress=Progress{completed=0, total=0}, error=CouchbaseLiteException{CouchbaseLite,10404,'Object Not Found'}}}
```

Comment: Is it Couchbase or CouchDB you are trying to connect to? Because Couchbase Lite only works with Couchbase, CouchDB is a different database

Comment: Then how can I connect android client and couchdb database ? @deniswsrosa

Comment: implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.7.0'

Comment: above dependency, I am using right now . That gives me an error. but 1.4.4 version is working properly @deniswsrosa

Comment: CouchDB is not Couchbase, and Couchbase Lite is only compatible with Couchbase. therefore there is no way of connecting Couchbase Lite with CouchDB. In order to make it work properly, you need to install Couchbase Server and Sync Gateway. Are you sure you are using CouchDB?

Comment: Btw, this log you added there is just a random log entry, it does not relate to your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206831/discussion-between-vishal-vaishnav-and-deniswsrosa).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve Connection error in couchdb android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59945185/how-to-resolve-connection-error-in-couchdb-android)